# Regex methods for extract function in tidyr using R for separating strings with different number of groups?

Tags: r, extract, tidyr, regex-group

I am reading in excel files to R that have different file names associated with their identity.  Some of these file names are only distinguished from each other by a final group label that is not present in the other files.

When I try to separate the files based on the final name using tidyr's extract() function, I cannot also parse the other condition.

For example, with the following filenames:
"Name1 Name2" and "Name1"

`d<-extract(d, filename, c("col1", "col2"), "(.*) (.*)",remove=FALSE)`

Leads to returned values of
col1 = "Name1" and col2 = "Name2" for the first filename, and NA for the second filename

Using the following regex:

`(.*)(| .*)`

returns the filenames in col1 gives NA for col2.

How would I separate these into different columns?

Name2 is always the exact same name after a space if that makes this easier in some way.

Comment: if the filename is "Name1," what are the two column names?

Comment: The filename upon reading becomes a column name "filename" that I am trying to extract into two new columns "col1" and "col2"

Comment: It's difficult to help you with so little information. Can you share some data / code and make your question more reproducible?